# Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico' because it violates

Tags: javascript, ajax, webpack, axios

I'm working on a Javascript App food2fork. But I get an error when AJAX call API promise fulfilled and render the results (Recipes). But when I click one of them it moves to the next page and say

> Cannot GET /47746

and give an error on the console

> Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback".

How to get rid of this kind of error?

Answer (score 3):

This is because a **Content Security Policy (CSP)** header is set somewhere in your application.

> Content Security Policy (CSP) is an added layer of security that helps
>   to detect and mitigate certain types of attacks, including Cross Site
>   Scripting (XSS) and data injection attacks./.../
>
> A CSP compatible browser will then only execute scripts loaded in
>   source files received from those allowlisted domains, ignoring all
>   other script (including inline scripts and event-handling HTML
>   attributes).
>
> As an ultimate form of protection, sites that want to never allow
>   scripts to be executed can opt to globally disallow script execution. *[edit: hence the "default-src 'none'" policy]*

More on CSP: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

You can create a CSP with online tools, like

- https://report-uri.com/home/generate
- https://www.cspisawesome.com

A CSP with `"default-src 'none'"` means that **nothing can be displayed/run on your domain** - you have to "whitelist" the services/content that you allow (**default-src** is a fallback for other resource types that do not have policies of their own, so you have it set like `none`, then you have to add sources that are explicitly allowed).

> A policy is described using a series of policy directives, each of
>   which describes the policy for a certain resource type or policy area.

### WHAT YOU CAN DO

In your case, you may need a policy something like:

`"default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'"`.

I'm pretty sure though, that as you go forward you'll need more rules, so check out the sources and the online CSP generators, so you won't have a hard time.

**OR** you may

1. Remove the CSP (not advised - it's a security measure)
2. For development purposes, you may set `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` (this way the CSP does not stop your content to be displayed/run, but shows "what would have been done, if not set to only to report the problems". Don't forget to handle this in production environment!)

### REFERENCE

- CSP reference: https://content-security-policy.com
- More on CSP: https://scotthelme.co.uk/content-security-policy-an-introduction/